# What is the connection between Moshiach and Tisha B'Av?

Tags: messiah, tisha-bav

I often see the following from [Yerushalmi Berachot](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l1102.htm) cited as a source that Moshiach will be born on Tisha B'Av:

> עובדא הוה בחד יהודאי דהוה קאים רדי געת תורתיה קומוי עבר חד ערביי ושמע קלה א"ל בר יודאי בר יודאי שרי תורך ושרי קנקנך דהא חריב בית מוקדשא געת זמן תניינות א"ל בר יודאי בר יודאי קטור תוריך וקטור קנקניך דהא יליד מלכא משיחא

What is the nature of the connection between Tisha B'Av and Moshiach? Are there other sources that discuss this relationship?

Comment: Perhaps that God makes sure we have the antidote when He sends the plague.

Answer (score 7):

It's brought down in some Sichos from the Lubavitcher Rebbe that there's a question: How can Hashem destroy the Beis Hamikdosh? There is halochos against destroying even a Shul.
The answer is that it was destroyed in order to build a nicer and better one. So the destruction -tisha b'av- is connected with the rebuilding -moshiach-.

Comment: Maybe He built it Al Tenai?

Comment: Did it have Kedushas Beis Hamikdosh even after the Shechina left?

Comment: @DoubleAA what do you mean by "maybe he built it Al tenai"? it has holiness, the rambam says we can bring korbonos on mokom hamizbe'ach

Comment: I'm going to add a related story with explanation from a sicha when I have time

Comment: But He didn't destroy mokom hamizbe'ach. Also, who says that a mokom hamizbe'ach designated Al Tenai is invalid for Korbanot?

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't get what you were saying. Are you saying maybe Hashem built it al tenai to destroy it?

Comment: al tenai to destroy it, or maybe al tenai that it would be temporary. Certainly He knew there would end up being a Churban.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're allowed to destroy shul built al tenai to destroy it?

Comment: Maamer Gadol Yiyeh Kavod HaBayis 5722

Comment: Amen ..........

Answer (score 4):

There are several. Some of them are [brought here](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/lkus/39/2/1/8) by the Lubavitcher Rebbe.

- Kabbalistically Kiddush Levana is said after Tisha B'Av because the afternoon is the time of the birth of Moshiach.
- Similarly, Rabbi Chaim Vital (the main student of the Arizal) says we can say Pesukei Nechama - verses of comfort, which are normally skipped on Tisha B'Av, at Mincha because it is the birth time of Moshiach. This brought in Halacha in the [Birchei Yosef](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7626&st=&pgnum=226&hilite=).
- The Pesikta Rabbati [says](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%98) that "Joy will only come on Tisha B'Av" - emphasizing the turnaround from its current status of mourning - which can be connected to the same idea.
- Based on the above he says that this is the inner reason why Tisha B'Av is called "moed" - a holiday.

Comment: Kiddush Levana isn't said in the afternoon though.

Comment: it's said that night after tisha b'av